# проверка введенной строки

Tags: java

Почему программа всегда выдает Error?

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Your Gender: male/female");
        String Gender =in.nextLine();

        if (Gender !="male" || Gender!="female") {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Начните с того, что покажите какой именно Error она выдает. Тяжело определять ошибки по состоянию облаков и кофейной гуще;)

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka, слово `Error` xD

Comment: У Вас условие просто такое, если это не мужичина или не женщина, то `Error`. Т.е. если будет мужчина, то это не женщина, поэтому вторая часть условия будет `true` и будет `Error`. и наоборот. Поменяйте условие.

Comment: `if (Gender !="male" || Gender!="female")` вслух проговорите и поймете что оно всегда срабатывает

Comment: Замените `||` на `&&` - если это не М и не Ж, то ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, у Вас логика следующая: напиши "Error" если: gender не равен male **ИЛИ** gender не равен female. Gender НЕ может являться и male, и female одновременно. Для правильности вам необходимо использовать **"И" (&&)**

Во-вторых, для сравнения строк вам необходимо использовать не "==", а **"equals"**. А для преобразования в "!=" вы должны поставить вначале поставить "!".

```
if (!Gender.equals("male") && !Gender.equals("female")) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```